# return keyword wont work... how to stop running of program?

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I had two buttons that do different job but there is check data entry in common 
so I made a program unit for that check then I call it from these two buttons 
but my problem is that when there is an error within the check I got the message for user and all things I made but the its get back to the code within button and continue progressing I set a **return** keywords at end of each condition to sop the code from running but its not working please whats the problem ? how I can stop my code until the error check passed ?!!

example of check data entry program unit

```
PROCEDURE CHECK_ENTRY IS
BEGIN
    IF  :block1.text_item1 IS NULL THEN 
            SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY('block1.text_item1',CURRENT_RECORD,VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'ERROR_ATR');
            SHOW_MESSAGE('example msg .');
            RETURN;
    ELSIF   :block2.text_item2 IS NULL THEN 
            SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY('block2.text_item2',CURRENT_RECORD,VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'ERROR_ATR');
            SHOW_MESSAGE('example msg2 .');
            RETURN;
END IF ;
END;
```

example of code within on_button_press trigger

```
PROCEDURE procedure_name IS

BEGIN

IF FORM_SUCCESS THEN
    DISPLAY_ERROR;

      :block1.text_item1:= :block2.text_item2;
      :block2.text_item2:=:block1.text_item1;

      **CHECK_ENTRY;**      /* here is the calling of previous program unit that check the data entry then  get back to here in case there is no error and continue commit the data and disabling text item so user wont be able to modify the data */

        COMMIT_FORM;
        program_unit('ORDER_DONE');         

ELSE
            ROLLBACK;
            DISPLAY_ERROR;
            SHOW_MESSAGE('please connect administrator.');
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: In **CHECK_ENTRY** what line exactly you think the error occurs? -- I don't see any handling of error in **CHECK_ENTRY**

Comment: null values in the text_items ill prompt for user to enter his name or other missing data  or number only in text_item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
PROCEDURE CHECK_ENTRY IS
BEGIN
    IF  :block1.text_item1 IS NULL THEN 
            SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY('block1.text_item1',CURRENT_RECORD,VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'ERROR_ATR');
            SHOW_MESSAGE('example msg .');
            raise form_trigger_failure;
    ELSIF   :block2.text_item2 IS NULL THEN 
            SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY('block2.text_item2',CURRENT_RECORD,VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'ERROR_ATR');
            SHOW_MESSAGE('example msg2 .');
            raise form_trigger_failure;
END IF ;
END;

PROCEDURE procedure_name IS

BEGIN
      :block1.text_item1:= :block2.text_item2;
      :block2.text_item2:=:block1.text_item1;

CHECK_ENTRY;
IF FORM_SUCCESS THEN
    DISPLAY_ERROR;

        COMMIT_FORM;
        program_unit('ORDER_DONE');         

ELSE
            ROLLBACK;
            DISPLAY_ERROR;
            SHOW_MESSAGE('please connect administrator.');
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for that key words raise form_trigger_failure which is like  break in c#